# I'm having a small issue using .push() to store data under key without replacing the childs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to generate a new push key and save the 2 children under it on each button click...however, Every time I submit my requests it either replaces the key or does not change anything if the data entered in my edit text is the same as it was initially entered here is my code.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    tvStoreName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStoreName);
    tvStoreName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email"));
    etDestination= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
    bAddNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddNew);


    bAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Request Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            String value1 = tvStoreName.getText().toString();

            String value3 = etDestination.getText().toString();

            reference.child("StoreEmail").setValue(value1);
            reference.child("Destination").setValue(value3);
        }
    });

    }}
```

Comment: Did you place any firebase rules that maybe preventing you from writing data? If not, then try add `...setValue(valueHere).onComplete(...)` and debug from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work !! the issue was caused because I did not include this..

```
             finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
```

to the bottom of my OnClickListener but I do have to say you guys are awesome !!

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I submit my requests it either replaces the key or does not change anything

It is correct.

Since you are using:

```
reference.child("StoreEmail").setValue(value1);
```

You can check the [official doc:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Using `setValue()` in this way **overwrites data at the specified location**, including any child nodes.

If you want to update data you have to use the `updateChildren()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `push().getKey()` on a DatabaseReference to get the key. If you want to save both data under same pushkey in different location, the following code will do that. But when you're updating data in multiple locations, it's always recommended to [do that in one call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) with `updateChildren()` method.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    tvStoreName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStoreName);
    tvStoreName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email"));
    etDestination= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
    bAddNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddNew);


    bAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Request Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            String value1 = tvStoreName.getText().toString();

            String value3 = etDestination.getText().toString();

            String key = reference.push().getKey();
            reference.child("StoreEmail").child(key).setValue(value1);
            reference.child("Destination").child(key).setValue(value3);
        }
    });

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Long story short**

If you want to set `value1` into this path `your-db-name\StoreEmail`, then you should change reference init like this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Hope this helps

---

**The description**

I just realize that `reference` object is result of `...push()` method. That makes every time you wrote

```
reference.setValue(yourValueHere);
```

it execute:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(yourValueHere);
```

Please note that `getReference().push()` will make one new random child uid in your database (like `your-db-name/-K83298jsdal`. So it makes your code, that looks like this:

```
reference.child("StoreEmail").setValue(value1);
```

will actually save new value (`value1`) at `your-db-name/-K83298jsdal/StoreEmail`